# Role-based Security with Forms Authentication , use database for users and roles

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm working on a web login application using forms authentication and role authentication.

I'm not so familiar with the role authentication , I've searched in google for some tutorials but I couldn't understand.

So ,

- 1.For creating an user with a certain role everything must be done here:

http://i1.asp.net/asp.net/images/pss/module08_06.jpg ( but , I want to store users info and roles in the asp.net sql database )

What I thought so far is to create a database with the followings table columns:

```
1.ID(int,primary)
2.Username(varchar(10))
3.Password(varchar(10))
4.RoleType(varchar(10)) - Roles are : Admin / User
```

On login , check if the `user&pass` are valid if yes then select the `roletype` from the database for the current user .

```
If roletype = Admin 
   Redirect to a certain page
else if roletype = user
   Redirect to other page
```

But I don't think asp.net web page knows that the column `RoleType` is used for `roles`  and it doesn't make sense , I mean there's no conection between    `<allow users="Admin"/>` and my column for called `RoleType`

```
<location path="\Admin\">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow users="Admin"/> //this 
            <deny users="*"/>
        </authorization>
```

So , if anyone wouldn't mind helping me , I would really appreciate.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ASP.NET Comes with a builtin tool for creating a User (Membership) and Roles Database which has all the correct schemas you will need.

I'd strongly suggest you start there, instaed of attempting to roll your own.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x28wfk74.aspx

Once you've done that, it's trivial to use the built in user/role management screens & the built in SqlMembershipProvider & SqlRoleProvider

**Edit**

After a quick google, ASP.NET seems to have a very good and detailed tutorial on asp.net membership & roles security

http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/security

You'll want to read that entire section on Membership, Roles & Admin.