# Is HttpContext.Current.User Safe for Stateless Session?

Tags: c#, session, azure, azure-web-roles

I have been using Azure Websites for couple of months and I decided to migrate to Cloud Services for SSL reasons. Since, I might need couple of web roles in my project, my session management need to be stateless.

This is how I deal with user data in my project. If I need user related data I get their username via `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name`. Using this info I query my database to fetch information about my users.

Is this to correct way to do it ? I made some research but could not find really clear info about where `HttpContext.Current.User` comes from.

So far, this is what I understand. User authenticates with Forms Authentication which creates a cookie in users PC. When server is requested by user again, server checks the cookie info and uses it to fill HttpContext object. If one of the other web roles takes the request next time, could it use that cookie to fill HttpContext ? (this could be all wrong, as I said this is what I understand from docs and other answers on web)

That is what I am trying to understand basically. I hope I explained my problem clear enough. Let me know If it is not clear.

Comment: if what you have in regards to filling / saving data using a cookie works ..then why not use that I only question one thing about that approach, what about user sensitive data.. are you storing data that can be compromised ??

Comment: it works but I dont have any idea how it would work in an environment with multiple web roles. also i only store their username in cookie. not me actually, i think forms authentication does that.

Comment: I would take a look at something like Role Based Security look at some of the answers and links provided on this StackOverFlow Post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11501450/role-based-security-with-forms-authentication-use-database-for-users-and-roles

Comment: I am using custom role based system but I dont think it is relavent to my question. thanks for your interest.

Comment: In general, authentication and session state have nothing to do with each other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your understanding is correct. When we use FormAuthentication, there will be a cookie generated once logged in, with the user information and something like token encrypted. Then we we request another page, browser will send this cookie to the server and ASP.NET will decrypt the cookie, validate and fill the user information into HttpContext.Current.User, no matter how many instances on your server side. So I think it's safe to use HttpContext.Current.User in a web role with multi-instance.

Answer (score 2):

I am using HttpContext.Current.User.Identity in an Azure app running on multiple web roles with SessionState disabled without any problems. I have set it up to use Cookies.

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/LogIn" cookieless="UseCookies" timeout="2880" />
</authentication>
```